# Please, I don't know greek!

Tags: cipher

| data | key | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7, 2, 17, 82, 56 | 0 | ΛΞλν |
| 1, 3, 8, 127, 65, 8 | 19 | εΤψΒΖ |
| 5, 64, 13, 9, 4, 42 | 7 | δδιΡΠ |
| 13, 9, 8, 657, 31, 3, 7, 5 | 3 | ? |

### Hints

> Hmmm, there's a repeating character in the third example?

> If there are repeating characters, there's probably a cycle.

Comment: I'm interested to see where this goes :)